# Paypal IPN POST Empty

Tags: php, json, post, paypal

I am trying to put the content of a POST request to my server in a file with no success.

The data is sent through POST, Raw:

```
POST /test-post.php HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxxx.ngrok.io
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

The PHP code to put this content in a file:

```
file_put_contents('post.json', json_encode($_POST));
```

It creates a the post.json file but this file is empty. What did I do wrong?

Full Raw Content:

```
POST /test-post.php HTTP/1.1

Host: xxx.ngrok.io

Accept: */*

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

User-Agent: PayPal IPN ( https://www.paypal.com/ipn )

correlation-id:b4eb634exxxx

CAL_POOLSTACK:queueserv-http-qtoc:DaemonChild*CalThreadId=0*TopLevelTxnStartTime=15fcae8137e*Host=slcsbsingle3001

CLIENT_PID:17707

Content-Length: 828

X-Forwarded-For: 173.0.xx.xx

payment_cycle=Monthly&txn_type=recurring_payment_profile_created&last_name=Martin&initial_payment_status=Completed&next_payment_date=02%3A00%3A00+Dec+17%2C+2017+PST&residence_country=FR&initial_payment_amount=8.00&currency_code=EUR&time_created=08%3A50%3A40+Nov+17%2C+2017+PST&verify_sign=XXXX&period_type=+Regular&payer_status=verified&test_ipn=1&tax=1.60&payer_email=XXXX%40gmail.com&first_name=Pierre&receiver_email=XXXX%40gmail.com&payer_id=XXXX&product_type=1&initial_payment_txn_id=XXXX&shipping=0.00&amount_per_cycle=8.00&profile_status=Active&charset=windows-1252&notify_version=3.8&amount=8.00&outstanding_balance=0.00&recurring_payment_id=I-XXXX&product_name=Abonnement+Pro&ipn_track_id=XXXX
```

**UPDATE**
It was a POST request to my server from a Paypal server for the IPN process

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/

And the problem was from the initialisation of the `L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0` variable in which I had put the special character € which is apparently forbidden.

Forbidden but in the set-up of the payment authorization to get the token, I had no error message, of course not that would be too easy. And no error message when I get the customer details as well.

No, you will just get an empty POST on the final IPN process if you put a forbidden character in `L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0`, and the € symbol is forbidden!

And you have to guess by yourself that if you get en empty POST it was because of `€`!

That was crazy, Paypal is (sometimes||often) a real nightmare.

Comment: What is the content?

Comment: How are you creating the POST?

Comment: Content is send from paypal sandbox in my ipn.php file.

Comment: I have added the full Raw content in the question

Comment: if you execute json_last_error() after conversion, you get something?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: @PatrickQ Nothing, it's like the server does not do anything if receiving POST data, even an echo 'Test'; is not displayed.

Comment: "It creates a the post.json file".  So is it doing something or not?  This statement and your one above are contradictory.

Comment: Is this pure PHP or some framework? Isn't there any redirects on url?

Comment: Pretty strange, it's creating empty file but does not display `echo 'test';`

Comment: @RauliRajande Pure PHP, no library opened, first lines of the file.